# How should I build a tree structure with svg elements?

Tags: reactjs, svg, force-layout

My goal is to build a clickable tree structure; every node is a SVG circle and when clicked it should reveal its (previously hidden) children. At the beginning only the root node is visible. The nodes should position themselves in such a way that they are not so spread out, and I guess the implementation of this will involve setting up a spring-like pulling force that controls the x and y coordinates of each node.

I'm learning React and have set up a function encoding all the SVG elements that make up a node; my problem now is the positioning. I would like to be able to have full control over each SVG element's coordinates but I fear I don't know how to properly do it- should I define a unique svg container for all the nodes? Should I group them someway?

I'm quite lost here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a force-directed graph. I would suggest you check out using d3 for this - it's a bit time consuming to code from scratch.  https://github.com/d3/d3-force

Comment: Actually a force-directed graph is overkill for this project as there are some simplifying assumptions- and d3 is not really what I'm looking for. The main question is how to correctly position the svg elements on the page as I don't understand it.